# parsing nested objects in a json using Karate tool

Tags: json, http, karate

From a Get method in Karate I'm getting the response in json.
Below is the first few lines of the response.

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "isBase64Encoded": false,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": "{\"result\": \"{'merchant_id': 609125186933, 'charge_month_duration': ['201801', '201801'],.....
}\"}"
}
```

from above I want to print the value of merchant_id or charge_month_duration in Karate print statement.
I tried the code like below

**Scenario:**

```
def jsonObject = 
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "isBase64Encoded": false,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type":         "application/json"
  },
  "body": "{\"result\": \".   {'merchant_id': 609125186933,     'charge_month_duration': ['201801', '201801']...
}\"}"
}
def body1 = jsonObject.body
print jsonObject.statusCode
print jsonObject.body
print body1
```

till here I'm getting the actual results.
But when I'm trying to return the value of result or `merchant_id` it is   returning null.

- `print body1.result`
- `print body1.result.merchant_id`
  Even I tried using jsonObject.body instead of body1. but it is also giving null.
  Could someone help me to get the value of the inner objects here. Please point out what wrong I'm doing.

Comment: please edit your question to simplify it instead of dumping your existing payload. you should be able to convey your need using some simple JSON e.g. `{ a: 1, b: 2 }`. refer stack overflow guidelines on a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you Peter Thomas, I edited my question and removed most of the unwanted part from the json payload. Didn't use the simple json because I was worried like I might not effectively convey my problem.

Comment: one more thing can you please paste VALID json, because others can cut and paste and try it out

Answer (score 0):

That JSON looks like it is very badly designed. I'm assuming this is what it was supposed to be:

```
* def response =
"""
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "isBase64Encoded": false,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "body": {
    "result": "{'merchant_id': 609125186933, 'charge_month_duration': ['201801', '201801'] }"
  }
}
"""
```

And then you can do this:

```
* def result = karate.fromString(response.body.result)
* match result.merchant_id == 609125186933
* match result.charge_month_duration[0] == '201801'
```